# Mysql query to reformat

Tags: mysql

I have a table the following columns and data :

```
Company     | Cash    | Acctrec   | Acctpay 
Comp1__     | 123     | 123       | 123  
Comp2__     | 123     | 123       | 123  
Comp3__     | 123     | 123       | 123  
Comp4__     | 123     | 123       | 123
```

I would like to present the data like :

```
Company     | Account | Amount
Comp1__     | Cash    | 123       
Comp1__     | Acctrec | 123        
Comp1__     | Acctpay | 123
Comp2__     | Cash    | 123       
Comp2__     | Acctrec | 123        
Comp2__     | Acctpay | 123
Comp3__     | Cash    | 123       
Comp3__     | Acctrec | 123        
Comp3__     | Acctpay | 123
Comp4__     | Cash    | 123       
Comp4__     | Acctrec | 123        
Comp4__     | Acctpay | 123
```

There is a very large number of companies.  How can I formulate a query to return the data like that?  Thanks!

Comment: What programming language is used to obtain and handle the query result?

Comment: Thank you, Strawberry.  The original data is in an excel spreadsheet and I tried to use excel powerpivot to get it into the format I want and couldn't do it.  I imported as is into mysql, and was hoping to have better luck massaging the data there.  I figured I would have to use some form of concat, group by, but was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: David : this will be a web report using php

Comment: Use 3 queries that each retrieve one of the columns, and combine them using `UNION`.

Comment: Companies shouldn't be estimated as columns. It should be records in other table and your table should be relates to this.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.  For sake of simplicity, I only added 3 columns of $ amounts.  I should have mentioned that there are actually 94.  Any way I can 'automate' it with a  loop through those column names?

Comment: Yeah, you should have mentioned that. Is there an Edit button?

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION` to combine queries that each retrieve one of the columns.

```
SELECT Company, 'Cash' AS Account, Cash AS Amount
FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT Company, 'Acctrec' AS Account, Acctrec AS Amount
FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT Company, 'Acctpay' AS Account, Acctpay AS Amount
FROM YourTable
```